# Does asp.net application/site impersonation affect other apps/sites on pool

Tags: asp.net, identity, impersonation, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

I have a problem authorizing some sql server databases, so in order to fix it tempory I use impesonate configuration section in my ASP.NET application.

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="abc" password="abc"/>
```

And everything works for me, this isn't a fix, it's just a workaround.
 But I wonder, does this affect other applications and services running on this application pool?

Also I'd like to know does it hurts perfomance issues significantly? AFAIK impersonation is executed for every request handled by this ASP.NET application.

Thanks.